# withCredentials using vanilla JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I can make a cross domain AJAX request with jQuery by passing the `xhrFields` property within the `$.ajax` object.

```
xhrFields: {
    withCredentials: true
}
```

I would like to optimize the speed however, so would like to test it against vanilla JS to see which is faster. How can I set `withCredentials` (or vanilla JS equivalent) without using a library like jQuery?

Comment: `xhr.withCredentials = true`

Comment: @RayNicholus Thanks very much. Can you show me the full code. I feel like `xhr` is where you've stored `new XMLHttpRequest();`, but haven't done vanilla AJAX before and would like to see how that line fits into the whole picture.

Comment: I'd argue that the biggest performance impact with Ajax requests is waiting for the response, so changing the way you make the call will be a negligible change, if any. And fwiw, you could have probably found the solution yourself, if you read the `xhrFields` documentation: *"An object of fieldName-fieldValue pairs to set on the native XHR object."* If you are unfamiliar with `XMLHttpRequest` have a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", "myserver.com");
xhr.withCredentials = true;
xhr.send();
```

Note that the above will not be noticeably faster than using jQuery to send the request.